# List of Numpy arrays passed to model is not the size the model expected

Tags: python, numpy

I am unable to solve this error. Can anyone solve this error? I shall be highly thankful in advance.

Below I attached my code and the error of that code:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-ec0e93dabcc7> in <module>
     82 # hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=58, nb_epoch=10, validation_split = 0.1, verbose = 1)
     83 hist=model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=10,
---> 84 validation_split=0.2,callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',min_delta=0.0001)])
     85 
     86 score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    951             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
    953         # Prepare validation data.
    954         do_validation = False

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    749             feed_input_shapes,
    750             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 751             exception_prefix='input')
    752 
    753         if y is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    100                 'Expected to see ' + str(len(names)) + ' array(s), '
    101                 'but instead got the following list of ' +
--> 102                 str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
    103         elif len(names) > 1:
    104             raise ValueError(

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 58 arrays: [array([[5.80e+17],
       [5.80e+17],
       [5.80e+17],
       [5.80e+17],
       [5.80e+17],
       [5.80e+17],
       [5.80e+17],
       [5.80e+17],
       [5.80e+17],
       [5.80e+17],
       [5...
```

The main error is

> List of Numpy arrays passed to model is not the size the model
>   expected

I have attached a screenshot of the code causing the error here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdGN7.png

Comment: Could you please copy the text of the code from your screenshot and include it in your post? Also, what is the broader scope of this code, so we can get a better idea of the context?

Comment: i added the code below

Answer (score 0):

```
def load_data(test_split = 0.5):
    print ('Loading data...')
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
   # df['sequence'] = df['sequence'].apply(lambda x: [int(e) for e in x.split()])
   #df = df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))

 #   train_size = int(len(df) * (1 - test_split))

#     X_train = df['symbol_count'].values[:train_size]
#     y_train = np.array(df['is_rumor'].values[:train_size])
#     X_test = np.array(df['symbol_count'].values[train_size:])
#     y_test = np.array(df['is_rumor'].values[train_size:])

    y = df['is_rumor']
    X = df.drop("is_rumor",axis = 1)
    xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = test_train_split(X,y)

#     print("X_Train")
#     print(xTrain.head())
#     print("X_Test")
#     print(xTest.head())
#     print("Y_Train")
#     print(yTrain.head())
#     print("y_Test")
#     print(yTest.head())


    xTrain = xTrain.values.tolist()
    xTest = xTest.values.tolist()
    yTrain = yTrain.values.tolist()
    yTest = yTest.values.tolist()


    return xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest
   # return pad_sequences(X_train), y_train, pad_sequences(X_test), y_test
def load_my_data():
    print ('Loading data...')
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
    y = df['is_rumor']
    X = df.drop("is_rumor",axis = 1)
    xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = test_train_split(X,y)
    x_train = []
    for i in xTrain:
        one_feature = df[i]
        x_train.append(one_feature)
    return x_train, yTrain, xTest, yTest

def create_model(input_length):
    print ('Creating model...')
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim = 188, output_dim = 50, input_length = input_length))
    model.add(LSTM(output_dim=256, activation='sigmoid', inner_activation='hard_sigmoid', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(LSTM(output_dim=256, activation='sigmoid', inner_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    print ('Compiling...')
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_my_data()

model = create_model(len(X_train[0]))
print("----------------checking--------------------------------------------")

print ('Fitting model...')
# hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=58, nb_epoch=10, validation_split = 0.1, verbose = 1)
hist=model.fit(X_tra`enter code here`in,y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=10,
validation_split=0.2,callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',min_delta=0.0001)])

score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=1)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```